# findstr returns no errorlevel when checking build log

Tags: batch

Jenkins is calling a batch script. This batch script builds a .NET project with `msbuild`, which is logged to a logfile.

Now I want to check if the build has failed. Part of this is done with these sort of commands:

```
findstr /N /C:"Build FAILED." %LOGFILE%
set "FINDSTRERR=%ERRORLEVEL%"
echo "FINDSTRERR: %FINDSTRERR%"
if "%FINDSTRERR%"=="0" (
    echo "ERROR: Build failed."
    exit 1
)
```

So the batch script searches the logfile for the string `Build FAILED` and if it is there, the batch script should exit with exit code `1`.

When I look to the output of these files, I see this:

```
6164:Build FAILED.
"FINDSTRERR: "
```

and script is running futher. But I am expecting something like `"FINDSTRERR: 0"`.

Why batch / findstr is not working here as expected?

Comment: hi, if this not work, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**[*FINDSTR will set %ERRORLEVEL% as follows:*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31810950/findstr-exit-codes-errorlevel)**

---

```
0 (False) a match is found in at least one line of at least one file.

1 (True) if a match is not found in any line of any file, (or if the file is not found at all).

2 Wrong syntax

An invalid switch will only print an error message in error stream.
```

---

---

- But I prefer not to do that with **`if | else errorlevel [0-2]`**, let me suggest that you try to manipulate the output command using **[&& operators (do this) |or| (do this)] [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58941744/how-do-i-find-if-any-one-of-the-words-in-a-file-is-in-a-very-long-string-which/58941831#58941831),** when doing this mechanical process, you will do the same as **`errorlevel`** (in an if  else condition); in addition, it will not be necessary to create a variable (**`%FINDSTRERR%`**) and applying its value update.

By doing this jobs with the operators, you can create your own **`errorlevel`** **0 | 1** from operators **`&& (1)||(0)`** according to your behavior:

---

```bat
@echo off && color 0a && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & title ...\%~nx0

set "LOGFILE=D:\path\to\folder\where\are\the\file_log\target.log" && echo[

"%__APPDIR__%\findstr.exe" /N /L /C:"Build FAILED\." "!LOGFILE!" >nul && (
echo/ [1] ERROR: Build Failed^^!! ) || (echo/ [0] Build: Successful^^!! )

"%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe" /t 2 >nul & endlocal && goto :EOF
```

---

- Output case **`&&`** ***Build Failed.*** string **match** in file.log:

---

```bat
[1] ERROR: Build failed!
 ^---:> == your errorlevel
```

---

- Output case **`||`** ***Build: Successful!.*** string **not match** in file.log:

---

```bat
[0] Build: Successful!
 ^---:> == your errorlevel
```

---

**Obs.:** - Edit: **`set "LOGFILE=D:\path\to\folder\where\are\the\file_log\target.log"`**, with full **`drive:/path/to/file.log...`**

---

Or...

```bat
@echo off 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "LOGFILE=D:\path\to\target.log"

findstr.exe /C:"Build FAILED\." "%LOGFILE%" >nul && (
     echo/ ERROR: Build Failed
   ) || (
     echo/ Build: Successful
   )

endlocal
```